# Best Way To Authenticate Restful API and Mobile App

Tags: java, php, rest, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I google search many time about how to authenticate Restful API and Mobile App.
I found a lot answers but I feel not better, or perhaps because I am new in API.

My Willing:

- Mobile App request or post data to Restful Server
- Restful Server Authenticate Mobile App by Username And Password Login
- I want to secure on Restful Server And avoid hacker steal password and request data.

After searching by google they told:

- use Https with SSL
- authenticate username or password then generate new token and signature
- use token and signature to authenticate Mobile App.
- Other way use Oauth 2.0. After reading Oauth 2.0 document,

I still think its structure still similar token and signature above.

I think if like that, mobile app can store or use token and signature,
or hacker can debug or see process log in by proxy request. 
I feel still not secure
because we still use token and signature on requesting.

I just start my new knowledge in API. If I misunderstand, 
I am sorry. I use PHP coding.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend jBoss's Keycloak (http://www.keycloak.org/). From the first page:

> Add authentication to applications and secure services with minimum
>   fuss. No need to deal with storing users or authenticating users. It's
>   all available out of the box.
>
> You'll even get advanced features such as User Federation, Identity
>   Brokering and Social Login.
>
> For more details go to about and documentation, and don't forget to
>   try Keycloak. It's easy by design!